# Oracle: Sorting by date and id

Tags: sql, oracle, date

I have the below statement

```
Select * from    
((Query A)
union all
(Query B)
union all
(Query C))
order by date,id
```

In all the query there is a

```
select tochar(date,'dd/mm/yyyy'), id
```

My output should order by date first then order by id, but my current out is e.g

```
01/01/2012
05/03/2012
12/02/2012
```

Its ordering based on the first 2 digits of the date, so how do i make it order by the whole date then id?

My date is a date, id is varchar.

Comment: (Btw, are you using Oracle or MySQL? Unclear...)

Comment: its oracle, could not tag oracle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you are ordering a `String` not a `Date`, because you convert all your date columns to char. Use:

```
order by to_date(date, 'dd/mm/yyyy'), id
```

Comment: If `date` is a `date` column converting it to `date` using `to_date()` does not make any sense. Just use `order by date` (and because ps4one is using `to_char()` on the column it is highly likely that the column is indeed of type `date`)

Comment: As I recall to_char converts Object to varchar2. Because ps4one is using it in every query union returns the column as varchar2.

Comment: But why convert a `date` to a `varchar2` and the convert it back to a `date`?

Comment: Probably because of the print-out. He could also use to_char in the main select, not convert in subqueries and then ordered by date.

Comment: The value in the `order by` is not used for "printout". And even for that there is no sense in converting a `date` into a `varchar` and then convert it back to a `date` which is then converted back to a character representation on "printout"

Comment: I ment the print-out of select stament. The select gives out a formated string (not date). I suggested the conversion to date because the column date vas converted to string in subqueries. And the convert is only in order by so it's orderd by date and not string. A i said the in previous comment: the other option would be that the conversion to_char would be used only in main select statement (which is now "select * ...."). In this case the subqueries must return date column as a date (without to_char conversion)

Answer (score 0):

The UNION need to consider them as a single table on which sorts and then do another.
If the column names are different in UNION just rename them with an ALIAS
Try this sql:

```
SELECT * FROM
(
SELECT 
       [id]      
      ,[date]      
  FROM 
       [TabellaA] 
  UNION ALL  
  SELECT
       [id]      
      ,[date]      
  FROM 
       [TabellaB]
  ) 
  AS TAB_OUTPUT  
  ORDER BY date,id
```